# How to update a random instance of a query in TypeDB?

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I have the following error:

### Error> [TQL03] TypeQL Error: There is a syntax error at line 11:

delete $connectsTo1 isa connectsTo;
^
extraneous input 'delete' expecting {, 'match', 'define', 'undefine', 'insert'}

I have the following query:

```
match
$sensor isa Sensor, has id $sensorID;
$segment1 isa Segment, has id $segment1ID;
$segment3 isa Segment, has id $segment3ID;
not { $segment1 is $segment3; };
$monitoredBy1(TrackElement: $segment1, Sensor: $sensor) isa monitoredBy;
$monitoredBy2(TrackElement: $segment3, Sensor: $sensor) isa monitoredBy;
$connectsTo1(TrackElement: $segment1, TrackElement: $segment3) isa connectsTo;
get $segment1ID, $segment3ID;
limit 1;
delete $connectsTo1 isa connectsTo;
insert $segment2 isa Segment, has id 555555;
insert $connectsTo2(TrackElement: $segment1, TrackElement: $segment2) isa connectsTo;
insert $connectsTo3(TrackElement: $segment2, TrackElement: $segment3) isa connectsTo;
insert $monitoredBy3(TrackElement: $segment2, Sensor: $sensor) isa monitoredBy;
```

This query should find a random instance of two segments that are monitored by the same sensor and they are connected to each other. Then delete the connection between them, create a new segment which wedges in between them and monitored by the same sensor.

I tried to run the query without the delete line. After that the first insert line was succesfull, but with the second insert line i got this error: **## Error>[THW15] Invalid Thing Write: The thing variable '$segment1' cannot be inserted as a new instance without providing its type (isa)**. It seems like the query doesn't recognises $segment1 anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get` clause makes it the `match` query.
TypeDB Studio just executes these lines as multiple queries.
And `delete` query can't be without a `match` clause.

If you delete the `delete` clause it will still see multiple queries - `match` query (with `match` and `get` clauses) and then `insert` query (which can be without a `match` clause, but it's lacking the variable bounding in this particular case).

I would suggest deleting the `get` clause. Then it should see the `update` (or `match-delete-insert`) query. Alternatively, you can try splitting these into multiple queries with `match` clauses for every query.

P.S. TypeDB language-specific libraries won't have this problem as in them you manually send each query and even select its type (every query type has a separate method to send the query).

P.P.S. Oh, and those insert keywords at the end - they are also creating separate queries (at least the TypeDB Studio treats them like that). If your intent was to send all these as a single query - drop the duplicate inserts. Only the first one should be sufficient.

Comment: I've rewrote the query as you suggested but i still get the same error. I think the limit 1; line still makes it a match query. However that is the point of my query to select one random instance because I have hundreds of matches. So my question is how can I pass the results of my match query into the delete and insert queries?

Comment: Yes, the limit is the problem. I don't believe we can limit the update query right now in TypeDB. That is why I created an issue for just that - https://github.com/vaticle/typeql/issues/284.

But it's a kinda strange thing to ask for a random instance. And the randomness of it is vague - as in not guaranteed to be random. Ideally, we would always want to use `sort()` with the `limit` to get more predictable results.

Comment: For now, you can always use a match query with `limit 1` to get exactly one instance, but add to the query results some data that can uniquely identify that instance (like ID). So that you can send a second query with that data but without a limit to update all instances matched (presumably only one instance will be matched).